# Expo hangs on CocaPods installation

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I've been trying to create a fresh app using `Expo` and following their documentation.

When running `expo init my-app`, it looks like the process hangs when trying to install CocoaPods. I left it running for 45 mins and nothing happened, I also typed out my password despite no prompt provided but I waited another 30 minutes and nothing happened again.

![expo hang]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDJ6m.png)

I also tried installing cocoapods with ruby and running `gem install cocoapods` but got the following error:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Hard to understand what exactly is happening here, but might lead me to another rabbit hole of errors.

Any suggestions or recommendations as to what I should do?